# Deriving 'frame dragging' in elliptical coordinates?

Tags: black-holes, rotation

I'm currently trying to derive the equation that demonstrates 'frame dragging'. I am familiar (of sorts) with the Kerr metric, but I am most comfortable working in cartesian/elliptical coordinates?

Is this still possible to derive, if so, can anyone help me?

Thank you for your time!

I have now derived that:$$ \Omega = \dfrac{r_s \alpha r c}{\rho^2(r^2 + \alpha^2) + r_s \alpha^2 r sin^2 \theta}$$

But what does $\Omega$ physically tell us?

Comment: $\Omega$ is the angular speed of the co-rotating reference frame. As it says on the Wikipedia page displaying this equation

Comment: Yes I know, but what I mean is how can we use this to determine the extra distance (for example) a satellite is dragged when orbiting the Earth? Is this even possible? Thank you in advance :-)